# GET API call for multiple URLS

Tags: api, loops, spotify, httr

I have about a years experience with R but really struggle to wrap my head around loops, i'd really appreciate any explanations you guys have with go with an answer!

I am trying to use the Spotify API to loop round a list of Music Categories (- this is the API term, they are termed Genre/Mood in Spotify App) and retrieve a list of playlists. To retrieve one categories playlists I can use the following:

I'd imagine this is a fairly simple problem which does not require testing and acquiring keys.
If required, keys can be easily acquired using Spotify documentation (linked below), I can help with setup if required (for this or any other Spotify project).

```
#Setup up; Store keys and authenticate 
ClientID <- "************"
ClientSecret <- "***********"

#OAuth 
spotifyEndpoint <- oauth_endpoint(NULL, 
                                  "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize", 
                                  "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token")
spotifyApp <- oauth_app("spotify", ClientID, ClientSecret)
spotifyToken <- oauth2.0_token(spotifyEndpoint, spotifyApp)


#Create URL to call
CatPlaylist <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/categories/","funk","/playlists",sep="")

#Call api using GET
CatPlaylist <- httr::GET(CatPlaylist, spotifyToken)

#Transform results form JSON
CatPlaylist <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(CatPlaylist)))

#Transform into df
CatPlaylist <- t(data.frame(CatPlaylist$playlists$items$name))
```

How would I loop through this to collect other categories, effectively replacing "funk" with something like "party" or "chill".

**Edit: Attempts added below**
I have tried the following, in which

`Cats`

Holds the full URL for each call.

```
final = NULL

for(i in 1:length(Cats)){
CatPlaylist <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/categories/",i,"/playlists",sep="")
CatPlaylist <- GET(CatPlaylist, spotifyToken)
CatPlaylist <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(CatPlaylist)))
  CatPlaylist <- t(data.frame(CatPlaylist$playlists$items$name))
final <- rbind(CatPlaylist,final)}
```

API documentation
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-categorys-playlists/

System info: R 3.3.2 R Studio Version 1.0.143 OS Sierra 10_12_3

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this. This struggle with loops so any suggestions are welcome but in the meantime the solution is below in case anyone else needs the answer!

```
#Get category playlist -  this works and returns a DF with rownames as categories. If country is not specified the API will return results which apply to all countries.
my.list <-list()
my.listOwner <-list()

for(i in 1:length(Categories$id)){
  CatPlaylist <- paste0("https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/categories/",Categories$id[i],"/playlists?limit=50&country=GB",sep="")
  miss.id <- Categories$id[i]
  list.name<- as.character(miss.id)
  a <- GET(CatPlaylist, spotifyToken)
  b <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(a)))
  my.list[[list.name]] <-data.frame(unlist(b$playlists$items$name))
  my.listOwner[[list.name]] <-data.frame(unlist(b$playlists$items$owner$id))
}

final <-do.call(rbind,my.list)
finalOwner <- do.call(rbind,my.listOwner)
```